# How works logging in Flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm using Flask to develop an API. Now I want to have a log to record what is happening in the API. But there are some things I don't understand, and I don't know why they work.

I have the following configuration.

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'wsgi': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'info_file_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/info.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'maxBytes': 485760,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
        'error_file_handler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/errors.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'maxBytes': 485760,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'handlers': ['wsgi', 'info_file_handler', 'error_file_handler']
    }
})
```

According to the official documentation, to use the logger I have to use:

```
app.logger.error('message')
```

But when I import *app* to use the *logger* in my different modules, I get an error of python circular import dependencies. So it doesn't work. All the examples I see, just use one file and they put everything in there (which is something I don't want).

Testing things, I used Python's logging module, without using the Flask logger variable. I import the module and use it.

```
import logging
logging.error('message')
```

And it is done correctly, it takes well the handlers of the above configuration and throw the logs in the respective files.

What I'm wondering is why it works well. I am not using the Flask variable (logger) and works. And I don't have any python circular import dependencies. I hope I've made myself clear.